# Finding the index of a header in a structured array for a part of the header name

Tags: python, arrays, string, find, structured-array

In my list there are strings such as

`A_list= ['mass_32_', 'mass_40_', 'mass_28_']`

I want to find the index of an element from an array of just the numbers.

For example

`masses=[32,28]`

I want to find the index of the ints in masses that correspond to the index in A_list.

Any suggestions of a for/while loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
[A_list.index('mass_{}_'.format(m)) for m in masses]
```